# How to put an Expander inside Datatemplate?

Tags: wpf

Strange one.

I have a contentcontrol on a WPF form, this loads a datatemplate within it.

This shows up fine (handwritten summary code so ignore errors/lack of attributes):

```
 <DataTemplate>
           <Label Content="Found datatemplate" />
  </DataTemplate>
```

This however renders blank

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Expander Header="Why dont I show">
        <Label Content="Found datatemplate" />
    </Expander> 
</DataTemplate>
```

I have set the expander to visibile, isexpanded to true etc and no matter what it doesn't render at all.

Confused- is this just not possible?

Comment: This ought to work, maybe post the real code instead of an approximation? The devil is always in those little details we couldn't be bothered to mention.

Comment: I remember vaguely that the content bindings need to be passed on to the children. Can you try <Expander Content="{Binding }".....>

Comment: Henk- Will play with it more as will take too long to anonymise. Have tried it in a blank form and it works. Mine is within a usercontrol and also templates being switched by Type, other content works fine, just expanders wont show. grrrr!!

Comment: Krishna- that brings up a "content is set more than once" error

Comment: _Have tried it in a blank form and it works._ - that's what I meant. Evolve that blank app until you can reproduce the problem.  Not much chance of us finding the answer otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently done something similar to what you're describing and it worked for me. I have an ItemsControl that binds to a collection of view models, each of which contains a UserControl representing custom content. I implemented the ItemsControl.ItemTemplate to display the custom control inside an Expander like this:

```
<ItemsControl Margin="0,20,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding ControlItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Margin="0,0,0,0"
                    BorderBrush="#E7E7E7"
                    BorderThickness="0,1,0,0"
                    Padding="20,0">
                <Expander Foreground="#E7E7E7"
                          IsExpanded="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,
                                        Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       FontSize="24"
                                       Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <ScrollViewer MinHeight="250">
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Control}" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Expander>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This is what my view model looks like:

```
public class SidePanelControlItem : ModelBase
{
    private bool _isExpanded;

    public SidePanelControlItem(UserControl control)
    {
        if (control == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("control");}

        Control = control;
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public UserControl Control { get; private set; }

    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return _isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            _isExpanded = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
        }
    }
}
```